# beamer - slide template

Tags: beamer

Is it difficult to set options to the code below so that my beamer slides will look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}  % or any other theme!
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: and what should happen to the miniframe navigation that comes with the Frankfurt theme when you have sections and ssections?

Comment: @dcmst: You are right... another theme can be used. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses TikZ for the drawings and the default (empty) theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \node(a)[fill=blue,rectangle,minimum width=.25cm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=north west]at(current page.north west){};
    \node[anchor=west]at(a.east){\insertframetitle};
    \draw[red](a.south west)--+(10,0);
  }
  \vskip.5cm % increase the skip if you want more space between the frame title and content 
} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture]\draw[blue,line width=1cm](current page.south west)rectangle(current page.south east);
}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To accommodate for two lines titles change the following lines:

```
\node(a)[fill=blue,rectangle,minimum width=.25cm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=north west]at(current page.north west){};
\node[anchor=west]at(a.east){\insertframetitle};
```

to:

```
\node(a)[fill=blue,rectangle,minimum width=.25cm,minimum height=1.2cm,anchor=north west]at(current page.north west){};
\node[anchor=west,text width=\textwidth]at(a.east){\insertframetitle}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make the frame title span over two lines?

Comment: @Marco see the edit